# Is it possible to view Vertice Index Numbers in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertices

I heard that viewing index numbers was on the developer dashboard for Blender, and I wondered if this has been implemented yet.

I'm talking about a view where the index number is displayed next to its vertice.

How do I see this information?

Comment: there are some free downloadable node groups who can do that. Just search for "blender geometry nodes index viewer"

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I have used two of them and they are a bit laborious. I was hoping that Blender 4.x had this integrated by now.

Comment: Blender has an ability to show vertex indexes, but only for editable data

Comment: it's native in 4.1 as a viewport overlay with the viewer node

Comment: @shmuel sounds promising, I will look forward to that release.  Does it work as simply as adding a viewer node and then enabling 'view indexes' in the viewport?

Comment: yes. (it needs 15 characters so here is extra text)